# hibernate.cfg.xml fails to reload with Tomcat/Spring 2

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm using an older Spring 2 application with Tomcat and Hibernate. I was under the impression that I could change some settings in hibernate.cfg.xml, restart Tomcat, and the new settings (like a database connection) would take effect. Yet the old settings persist. What do I have to do to make these new changes go through? Here is an example of the xml:

```
<property name="connection.username">career</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.76.46:1521:ISDD</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
    <property name="myeclipse.connection.profile">my-careers</property>
    <property name="connection.password">farcri</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
```

Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: What exactly are the changes that have been done in the hibernate.cfg.xml? Have you checked if the work directory in tomcat is getting refreshed with the new cfg.xml (assuming the cfg file is conatained within the .war) ? Please share the tomcat console o/p as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, hibernate.cfg.xml was not being read by the application. Instead, the database connection settings were placed in the ROOT.xml file in localhost. Not sure why this would be advantageous. Here is the relevant section of the ROOT.xml file:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/careers" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.76.55:1521:ISDD"
          username="career" password="farcri" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
          maxWait="-1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what your new settings are.Anyway they should be found.do you want to change database from one provider to oracle.Please put your tomcat output..You can do one thing that include log4j jar files so that you can see what tomcat is doing in detail manner.i think you are using myeclipse..do project clean such things..go to project and right click then do refresh..do close myeclipse and start again.

Hope this helps to you to figure out your problem.